# Fazer cálculos baseados em médias PHP ou MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arduino

Um amigo criou um projeto no Arduino que monitora consumo de energia em Kw/h. Ele a cada 5 minutos insere a informação do consumo no banco MySQL.

A cada 5 registros eu preciso fazer a média deles, e depois, pegar a média e multiplicar por 15.

Posso fazer isso tanto no PHP quanto no MySQL, alguém poderia me dar uma dica de como fazer uma listagem com todas as médias de 5 em 5?

Comment: Isso deve servir para calcular a média das últimas 5 leituras. `SELECT AVG( consumo ) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5` - Agora, qual o sentido de fazer média para multiplicar? Some tudo e multiplique por três, dá na mesma.

Comment: Boa noite @Bacco eu fiz,mais ele ta trazendo a media somente de 5,o que preciso é que ele me dê uma média a cada 5.

Comment: @Bacco Segue o select: SELECT AVG(Consumo)AS CONSUMO FROM Leitura  ORDER BY Id DESC LIMIT 5

Comment: Você quer uma listagem com todas as médias de 5 em 5? seria legal editar a pergunta e deixar mais claro, se for isso. A solução seria acrescentar algo como um GROUP BY INT(id / 5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para obter uma listagem com as médias multiplicadas por 15:

```
SELECT AVG( consumo ) * 15 AS media_consumo
   FROM leitura
   GROUP BY FLOOR( ( id - 1 ) / 5 )
   ORDER BY id
```

Veja funcionando no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b9792/1)**.

De curiosidade, a média x 15 dá no mesmo que a soma multiplicada por 3:

```
SELECT SUM( consumo ) * 3
```

Veja funcionando no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b9792/2)**.

**Nota:** este tipo de agrupamento só faz sentido se os `id`s forem contínuos.

Comment: só testei agora,desculpa a demora no retorno. Deu o seguinte erro: SQL execution error #1064. Response from the database. You have an error in your SQL syntax.; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY FLOOR ((id-1)/5)'at line 4 ... retornou essa mensagem.

Comment: assim também não deu: GROUP BY INT(id / 5)  , observação,já alterei a pergunta.

Comment: @OtácioBarbosa Tinha um erro de digitação aqui na resposta, mas a demonstração no SQLFiddle estava correta, chegou a ver? De qualquer forma, agora corrigi a daqui. A posição do ORDER estava errada na resposta.

Comment: Poxa e nem me atentei também,vacilei,me desculpa. Era exatamente isso que precisava,obrigado pela ajuda. Abração.

Comment: @OtácioBarbosa não prometo, mas se der um tempinho mais tarde, ponho uma versão PHP como exemplo. É bem simples de fazer, mas eu não gosto de publicar sem testar (testando eu já faço besteira às vezes kkk)

Comment: À propósito, só uma curiosidade, qual seria a razão de multiplicar por 15? Não seria por 12, pra dar o valor por hora? `60 / 5 = 2.4`  e `2.4 * 5 = 12`. Se for pra calcular por hora, seria a soma dos 5 multiplicado por 2.4 (ou a média por 12).

Comment: Recebi a informação que a cemig calcula a cada 15 minutos,fazendo o calculo 15 eu consigo ver o gasto e tentar basear em um valor de energia gasto,assim podendo detalhar um painel de monitoramento.

Comment: @OtácioBarbosa experimente fazer uma média geral também, talvez seja mais simples e mais preciso. Acho que se for pra calcular a cada quinze, bastaria pegar grupos de 3 em vez de 5. Mas posso estar falando besteira, já que não sei detalhes...

Comment: @Bacoo certo,vou fazer todos os testes e depois retorno como foi.

Answer (score 0):

O cálculo de média é basicamente a soma dos elementos dividido pelo número de elementos.

Exemplo de cálculo de média: `(1 + 2 + 3 + 4) / 4 = 2,5`.

Neste sentido, no PHP, você pode fazer assim:

```
function myCalc($data = [], $param = 15) {
     return (array_sum($data) / count($data)) * $param;
}
```

E na query SQL:

```
select (SUM(campo_numerico) / COUNT(campo_numerico)) * 15) AS calculo  from TABELA order by ID desc LIMIT 5;
```

ou

```
select (AVG(campo_numerico) * 15) as calculo from TABELA order by ID desc LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: Bom dia, Assim deu certo a media sim,mais eu preciso que seja como o @Bacco falou que mostre todas as medias do db,ou seja uma lista de medias. Exemplo: os banco tem 1000 registros, a cada 5 registros ele vai calcular a media,e vai me lsitas todas as médias. No caso de 1000 registros ele me retornaria 200 médias.